# Model Documentation role

Tags: models, quantitative

first timer here,I received an 'inmail' on linkedin from a recruiter regarding a role in model documentation team as part of the quantitative modeling and analytics department of a 'global bank'. The exact bank wasn't stated hence couldn't find more info online. I am personally interested in the general quant finance space(quant trading, quant portfolio management, quant analysis).My dilemma is ,Is a model documentation role a full blown career path or is it an entry level path reserved for entrants who move on to wider quant roles(I'm confused because Ive never heard of it)?I know there are definitely people who document models but I dont know if it's a long term career(or not).If anyone knows about or has been in this this role in general , kindly pass on some info.

A bit of context on my background.Bsc.Actuarial Science,Msc.Mathematical Modelling, Equity research for a year(in Africa,emerging market), Data science Associate , planning to take CFA and FRM(soon as I can afford it)